# Setting value for DB2 varchar for bit data column

Tags: types, type-conversion, db2

In a DB2 database on Windows, I have a table with a column of data type 'varchar for bit data'. I insert a record in this table, and set a value for this column.
When I select the record after that, I see a different value for this column then the value I set in the insert statement. It is obviously being converted implicitly.
The value I want to see in this column when I select this record is '38E2C310275B6A8F7E966E9B529741BC'. Which value do I use in my insert statement to achieve this?

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table fbd ( a varchar(32) for bit data)

insert into fbd(a) values X'38E2C310275B6A8F7E966E9B529741BC'

select a from fbd

A                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
x'38E2C310275B6A8F7E966E9B529741BC'                                



select hex(a) from fbd

1                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------
38E2C310275B6A8F7E966E9B529741BC
```

Comment: Thanks mao. That is exaclty what I was looking for.