# DB2 encrypt() problem with PHP and parameterised query

Tags: php, db2, prepared-statement, password-encryption, db2-400

I am trying to change some SQL code to use parameters instead of hard-coded data.

This code is causing difficulty:

```
Update mytable set passw=encrypt(?, 'mysecretkey') where ...
```

The passw field is `VARCHAR(128)` for `BIT DATA`. Replacing the old code (putting new password directly into SQL) with `?` ended in an SQL error about missing type binding.

Using stackoverflow I found the [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037741/setting-value-for-db2-varchar-for-bit-data-column):

```
Update mytable set passw=encrypt(CAST(? as VARCHAR(128) FOR BIT DATA), 'mysecretkey') where ...
```

However this update SQL runs ok, but the password is not recognised anymore.

The SQL reading it uses

```
select decrypt_char(passw, 'mysecretkey') as PW from...
```

and here something totally differnt comes out.

What did I do wrong?

Full example

**Working (without parameters)**

```
$options=array();
$conn = db2_connect('xx', 'yy', 'yy', array());

$sql="
    update SHOPUSERS 
    set PASSWD=encrypt('newpassword', 'mysecretpassword')
    where SHOPID=1 and 
    CUSTOMERNO='999'  
 ";

 $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

$fireDB2=db2_execute($stmt, array());

$sql="
    Select decrypt_char(PASSWD, 'mysecretpassword') as NEWPASSWD from SHOPUSERS  
    WHERE   SHOPID=1 and CUSTOMERNO='999'
";
$query=db2_exec($conn, $sql);
$ret=db2_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($ret);
```

Output:

```
array(1) { ["NEWPASSWD"]=> string(11) "newpassword" }
```

**Not working (with parameters)**

```
$options=array();
$conn = db2_connect('xx', 'yy', 'yy', array());

$sql="
    update SHOPUSERS   
    set PASSWD=encrypt(CAST(? as VARCHAR(128) FOR BIT DATA), 'mysecretpassword')
    where SHOPID=1 and 
    CUSTOMERNO='999'    
 ";

 $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

$fireDB2=db2_execute($stmt, array("newpassword"));

$sql="
    Select decrypt_char(PASSWD, 'mysecretpassword') as NEWPASSWD from SHOPUSERS   
    WHERE   SHOPID=1  and CUSTOMERNO='999'
";
$query=db2_exec($conn, $sql);
$ret=db2_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($ret)
```

Output:

```
array(1) { ["NEWPASSWD"]=> string(19) ">ÁÏø/ËËÏ?ÊÀ" }
```

Konfig:

```
PHP 8.1.27, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 
ibm_db2 driver Version 2.1.5, 
IBM DB2 i5/OS V7 Release 4 M0
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you're using as well please? We need a [mre] of the issue. P.S. Passwords are supposed to be _hashed_, not encrypted.

Comment: Beware (1) `encrypt()` is deprecated and might be removed in future Db2 releases  (2) better practice is to OMIT the key and to supply it separately via a hostvariable with the `set encryption password` statement, (3) the returned item from enrypt() is LONGER than the plain-text (by up to 15 bytes or so , meaning you have to double check that it fits and (4) on Db2-LUW the max length of they key is 127 bytes.

Comment: I added a full example with PHP.
Thanks for the hint about encrypt deprecated, unfortunately I am not able to change the database structure.

Comment: Just a terminology note: both versions of your code use prepared statements (hence the "prepare" and "execute" calls in both). The only difference appears to be the use of _parameters_ in the second version, instead of hard-coded values in the query. It helps to be precise and clear when you're explaining what's happening

Comment: Yes, the question needs editing to correct the misleading description and title, and to add exact details of the environment, versions, which drivers being used etc. Regardless of that, both supplied code fragments yield the same output in my environment. Linux x64, db2 v11.5 , php 7.2.24, ibm_db2 2.0.8. So there is something amiss with the configuration or the fragments of code differ substantially from what is really running.

Comment: PHP 8.1.27, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
ibm_db2 driver Version 2.1.5
IBM DB2 i5/OS V7 Release 4 M0

Comment: You forgot to update the terminology too...I've fixed that for you now (and improved the formatting and a couple of grammar issues)

Comment: Most likely a driver problem. The support for IBM i by the pecl php ibm_db2 is deprecated, and IBM recommends that users instead use the PDO_ODBC or odbc extension with the i-access-driver .  See https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2?tab=readme-ov-file